# Writing multiple lists across multiple lines in .txt file

Tags: python

I have a CSV with thousands of lines of feedback for people where I work.  I have split the CSV into lists for each person, but I need to write this to file and have all the lists written onto it with each comment on a separate line.

At present I am using a stupid solution of just looping each list separately like this:

```
with open('sgf.txt', 'a') as t:
    for item in jolist:
        t.write('%s\n' %item)
    for item in adamlist:
        t.write('%s\n' %item)
```

There must be a way to do this without writing out all these lines though (as I have about 30 lists), and this also does not leave a space between the separate lists.

Comment: You are aware that a CSV may not be the best approach to structure this data, aren't you?

Comment: It's a little confusing to understand what exactly are you trying to make better. The data format? The output format? Size? Speed?

Comment: Why don't you store your 30 lists in a main list that you can loop too?

Comment: Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. In particular, it's unclear what your input is, what your current code is, what the output is and what you would expect it to be. Please extract a [mcve] that provides that info.

Comment: I have the data in a CSV format, and it just has about 30,000 odd comments which contain people's names.  Most of the comments are non specific, but I need to pull specific comments which contain direct feedback for people from the CSV, and then make this into a list.  I am aware I can essentially just make this as 1 list, but I want to have the separate lists as well, and am just interested in how to do this for learning purposes

Comment: @AlexEdwards: in order to get the question reopened, could you please edit it, show some example lines of data and add specifics?

Answer (score 2):

The incorrect factor in your approach, that is making yur task cumbersome, is having hardcoded, in program, variables for each person in your data.

The people names are data - and as such, they should not be set to variable names. If you have 30 variables, the only way to go through all of them is to repeat code
for each (although the use of functions could minimize the amount of repeated code). (And yes, there are automated ways of walking through all the variables, but this is not basic programing, nor the best approach).

What you should be doingis keeping your data in a *dictionary* instead.
So, in place of `jolist`, `adamlist`, ... you data will be in a `comments` dictionary, and be acessible as:

```
comments = {}
comments["jo"] = ...
comments["adam"] = ...
```

Under this approach the names are *data*, not variable names, and you can iterate over all names (and their associated content) doing:

```
...
output = open("output.txt", "wt")
for name, comment_list in comments.items():
    for comment in comment_list:
         # ensure a comment have no line breaks:
         comment = comment.replace("\n", " ")
         output.write(f"{name} - {comment}\n")
output.close()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  This makes a lot of sense. As you can tell I'm pretty new.  I have used dictionaries, but still very much learning when something is appropriate.

Comment: Note that while I genereatead a text file with author - comment, oone per line, I did not do a "csv" - instead, it is more "human readable" . It will work as a CSV if you use a " - " as the field separato, though.

For a proper CSV, however, the correct thing would be to use Python's CSV module, which can properly handle separator  ocurrences inside the text data. I preferred not to use it to keep the example simple, above.

Answer (score 0):

- Instead of a list, better for your input to be a dict, keyed on person's (unique) name, so you can iterate over it, instead of hardcoding lookups like `d['jo'], d['adam'], ...`
- Each dict entry for a single person can just be a single item, with newlines `\n`. No need to split the CSV into a list for each person, that just makes things harder.
- You need multiline CSV, with whitespace escaping, so I strongly recommend you use pandas [`to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)/ [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), rather than Python's crappy [builtin `csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

Example code:

```
import pandas as pd

# It's simpler to directly create a dataframe. But if you want to import your existing dict:
comments = {
 'jo':   'Could try harder\nAn apple a day makes the IT department bankrupt\n',
 'adam': 'Don\'t snore heavily during my presentations\nImprove the XYZ\n'
}

comments_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(comments, orient='index', columns=['Comments'])

comments_df.to_csv('out.csv', line_terminator='\n')
```

Comment: Thanks, going to go the dictionary route!